# How to pass Iterator<String> as Iterator<&str>?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn my_print<'a>(args: impl Iterator<Item=&'a str>) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("=> {}", arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()];
    my_print(vec.into_iter()); // how to pass vec here?
}
```

How do I convert `Iterator<T>` to `Iterator<U>` and pass it to another function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An even better way would be to write the function in [a way such as it doesn't actually care](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48bec044e2ba59f319dee2f53163c7eb):

```rust
fn my_print<T: AsRef<str>>(args: impl Iterator<Item = T>) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("=> {}", arg.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()];
    my_print(vec.into_iter()); // works!
}
```

---

If you cannot change the function signature, [you have to convert the iterator beforehand](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce0479a082c0ef5e7b6bbd0795a3bc67):

```
fn my_print<'a>(args: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("=> {}", arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()];
    my_print(vec.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref()));
}
```

Note that in that case you cannot use `into_iter` because no-one would own the strings.

Answer (score 2):

> How do i convert `Iterator<T>` to `Iterator<U>` and pass it to another function?

You use the `map` adapter function of `Iterator`.

---

In your particular case, you need to:

1. use `iter` instead of `into_iter`, that makes the vec live longer than the function call
2. `map` the `String`s to `&str`

```rust
fn my_print<'a>(args: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>) {
    for arg in args {
        println!("=> {}", arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()];
    my_print(vec.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref()));
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d290d17d0bb7b4ce1460c082e9064851)