# How do you convert Vec<&mut T> to Vec<&T>?

Tags: casting, rust

I've got a vector of mutable references:

```rust
struct T;
let mut mut_vec: Vec<&mut T> = vec![];
```

How can I pass (a copy of) it into a function that takes a vector of immutable references?

```rust
fn cool_func(mut immut_vec: Vec<&T>) {}
```

Comment: You can't copy nor clone mutable references, so you can't copy or clone a vector of mutable references.

Comment: @mcarton But can you convert a mutable reference to immutable references, if the immutable reference is never used during the lifetime of the mutable references?

Comment: Yes but that moves the mutable reference, so you wouldn't be able to keep the original vector.

Comment: Why do (you think) you need this? Vectors of references are fishy enough as they are, but trying to have simultaneously several vectors of references to the same elements with different mutability seems weird.

Comment: @mcarton In a loop, I'm running a function to check which resource has the most time left (the function), then subtracting the time required for a particular task from that resource (among other things). I only need this copy to pass into the function, since the function mutates the vector it's given.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. I'd recommend asking a seperate question with a more representative example of what you're trying to achieve - my hunch is that there's likely a more 'rust-y' way to approach it.

Comment: @JoeClay [I've posted the "X" here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56756713/5223757), though the title's rubbish and I'm not sure of the tags to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **need** to actually *convert*, see [Joe Clay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754449/155423). However, you might not need to convert in the first place!

Instead of changing the argument, change the function so that it accepts both mutable and immutable references. Here we use [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) to abstract over both:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    let mut st = String::new();

    let mut_vec = vec![&mut st];
    cool_func(mut_vec);

    let immut_vec = vec![&st];
    cool_func(immut_vec);
}

fn cool_func<S>(_: Vec<S>)
where
    S: Borrow<String>,
{
}
```

See also:

- [How to pass Iterator<String> as Iterator<&str>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55948343/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Answer (score 5):

You can dereference and reborrow the mutable references, then add them to a new `Vec`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut st = String::new();

    let mut_vec = vec![&mut st];
    let immut_vec = mut_vec.into_iter().map(|x| &*x).collect();

    cool_func(immut_vec);
}

fn cool_func(_: Vec<&String>) {}
```

Note however, that this consumes the original `Vec` - you can't really get around this, as if the original `Vec` still existed, you'd have both mutable and immutable references to the same piece of data, which the compiler will not allow.

Comment: Is there a way to promise the compiler that I won't use the mutable references during the lifetime of the immutable references?

Comment: You can't have a mutable reference to something at the same time as an immutable reference. There are wrapper types that can shift enforcement of this to runtime (`RefCell`, `Mutex`, etc.), but they're something of a last resort.

Comment: *you can't really get around this* — [why not](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=daa16f05da13036c8a383d99522205ac)?

Comment: While this seems to explicitly reallocate, it turns out that LLVM will optimize the allocation out as soon as opt level is at least 2: https://godbolt.org/z/rT56WrbM9