# How can I represent this data?

Tags: types, architecture, rust

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56754101/5223757) on this topic has been correctly identified as an instance of the [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/308065)

I'm trying to create a resource management crate to decide who gets to rent the flooble. The public interface (currently) looks sort of like this:

```
pub struct Bid<T> {
    max_bid: TokenPerNanoSecond,
    budget: Token,
    data: T
}

/// Returns a vector of tuples of (T, time of rent end, tokens spent)
pub fn who_rents_the_flooble<'a, T>(
    mut bids: Vec<&'a mut Bid<T>>
) -> Vec<(T, NanoSecond, Token)> {
    let mut output = vec![];
    let mut now = NanoSecond::from(0);
    // while bids.len() > 0 {
        // run a mini auction to work out who wins
        // increment now by the duration
        // append winner's data, now and amount spent to output
        // subtract amount spent from winner's budget
        // remove bids with no budget left
    // }
    output
}
```

`Token`, `NanoSecond` and `TokenPerNanoSecond` are newtypes of `u64` with their arithmetic relationships fully defined; they're mostly present just because I'm bad at algebra, and don't want subtle bugs popping up because of my basic algebra mistakes and conflation of semantically different data.

`T` is a purely opaque thing. It's the `void *` of C callbacks, acting as a way for the caller to identify the relationship between what went in and what's come out.

However, `Vec<&'a mut Bid<T>>` doesn't really do what I need it to do. In order to implement the "mini auction", I need to re-order a `Vec<&'a Bid<T>>` copy of `bids`, which requires taking ownership of the references and will leave me a little bit stuck when I next need to mutate the `Bid`s.

What should my architecture look like?

---

If this isn't enough information, note that I'm trying to re-implement [this bad code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212170/86025) in Rust.

Comment: Why not just take in `Vec<Bid<T>>`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I thought of that about 2 hours ago, and it seems to have solved most of the problems. I was going to finish writing the program before writing up an answer, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

All of these problems can be solved simply by taking ownership of the vector; your prototype should look like this:

```
pub fn who_rents_the_flooble<T>(
    mut bids: Vec<Bid<T>>
) -> Vec<(T, NanoSecond, Token)>
```

Passing by value, not by reference, solves the problem.